# Global (Ising) Gates and ZX-calculus representation

Tags: gate-synthesis, zx-calculus, ising-model

I could find from [this source](https://journals.aps.org/pra/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevA.102.022406?casa_token=fcRzcfSj3TQAAAAA%3AYAqYvFH3rHmBJIPzQNme1j1eiQ7LKtHQlajvnuAsrJqeIlB5JIvVEkPajKr7DMqnujzsAlwDYXraVw) -- but also from other works on ZX-calculus -- the following extract:

[image]

This looks to me as a generalisation of a 2-qubit Ising gate to an $n$-qubit global Ising gate. Especially considering that the 2-qubit case [admits the following synthesis](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/6791/8954):

[image]

I find global gates particularly interesting, hence I am intrigued by the compactness of this representation, both mathematical and graphical.

Is my statement correct, namely, that this representation is a generalised Ising gate?

Comment: Yes a phase gadget (which is a CNOT ladder, then a phase, and another CNOT ladder) implements $e^{-i \alpha/2 Z\otimes \cdots \otimes Z}$ and in that sense it is a generalisation of the Ising interaction.